# How to set break points in vsCode in a Svelte application

Tags: svelte, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug a js file in my svelte App using vscode.

The de-bugger starts correctly and the application runs. I suppose this means that my *launch.json* is correct.

But vsCode will not set a break point:

> Unbound breakpoint, Some your breakpoints could not be set ...

I am guessing that this is because Svelte compiles the source and it should be "parsed from a sourcemap". I have no idea how to fix this. can someone help?

Comment: I've tried setting a breakpoint in bundle.js (which I assume is the 'compiled' file bu that raises the same issue. Does this mean it's not possible with Svelte?

Comment: Thank you so much for that - assumed that the console debugger would suffer the same problems, but I tried it and it works fine. Perhaps you should work this up into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting breakpoints in the compiled output. Source maps tend to not work all that well. That is because Svelte generates a lot of internal code that makes mapping the source correctly difficult.

If it is still unbound, the debugger does not have enough or the wrong information when trying to determine what path corresponds to which file. E.g. the browser path `/bundle.js` could locally be `/dist/scripts/bundle.js`.

I would suggest getting a browser-specific debugging extension and reading its documentation or just use the browser dev tools, which is what I do. When you set a breakpoint there, you can be sure it will be hit.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching this same problem with an unbound breakpoint when debugging sveltekit code using VSCode.

My solution is a combination of various answers found online. Here's what I did:

1. you don't need anything special in launch.json
2. In VSCode, cntrl-shift-p and then choose "Debug: Javascript Debug Terminal
3. Do "npm run dev" in the VSCode terminal, and it should tell you that the debugger is attached.
4. Any breakpoints you've set will be properly colored red, in your normal svelte code (in, for example, +page.server.ts, not the compiled version)
5. Exercise the code from localhost:5173 and when it stops due to the breakpoint, the debug commands (i.e. next, step-into, etc) are at the top of the VSCode window.
6. The debug panel on the left side will open automatically if not already opened, where you can see the variables, call stack, etc.